# Missing quotation marks in cmd echo

Tags: cmd

I have the following cmd command to open every video inside of my startup folder:

```
for %v in (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\"Start Menu"\Programs\Startup\*.mp4) do start "" %v
```

Executing this command, the following is being displayed in console:

```
C:\Users\username>for %v in (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\"Start Menu"\Programs\Startup\*.mp4) do start "" %v

C:\Users\username>start "" C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\animation.mp4
Die Datei "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start" kann nicht gefunden werden.
```

**Simply put, the error says that the given file can't be found.**

I reckon what's going wrong is, that the video is indeed being found (as you can see in the second echo), but the file path's quotation marks around "Start Menu" are missing. How do I solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to escape `Start Menu` due to the whitespace, in truth you should quote the whole path. Try with this, instead:

```
C:\Users\username>for %v in ("C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\*.mp4") do start "" %v
```

This might not be enough, because `start "" %v` needs quoting as well. In that case, try

```
C:\Users\username>for %v in ("C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\*.mp4") do start "" "%v"
```

*Edited after the precious inputs from the comments*. Please, do have a look on the great explanation regarding `"%v"` vs `"~%v"` in the comments, as well.

Comment: `start "" "%v"` should actually read `start "" "%~v"`. And this is not really called [escaping](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) (see the `^` character for that), this is [quotation](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)...

Comment: @aschipfl, you are correct, thanks indeed. I've edited the answer to reflect your inputs.